# Can I set my Mac up to take a screenshot everytime I left click?

Tags: terminal, automator, screen-capture

I understand I am able to set my mac up to screenshot using timed intervals. But is it possible to set something up, in terminal perhaps, that would allow me to automate my screenshots so that every time I left-clicked a full display screenshot was taken?
I want to track my daily workflow for a university project.
Could I also direct the screenshots to a specific folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's the best way to track your daily workflow? There may be better, automated ways of producing data on your activities, rather than a bunch of images which you'll have to look through and type up. There are also apps that can provide reports of your usage.

Answer (score 2):

I have my doubts that mapping left click to screenshot is a great idea. It renders mouse as pointing device useless and you may end as some Vim users: "I've been using Screenshot for about 2 years now, mostly because I can't figure out how to exit it."

To set folder where screenshots are saved:

- Press **⇧⌘5** or open Screenshot with Spotlight (⌘ Space; enter Screenshot in Spotlight search field).
- Select 'Options', and set 'Save to' as one of defaults or 'Other locations.

To take screenshot (full screen):

- **⇧⌘3**

This takes screenshot of full screen and saves it to folder set.

I think that pressing three keys is simple enough solution. It takes advantage of the workflow built into macOS, no need for Automator scripts nor remapping.

For more information have a look at Apple documentation: [Take a screenshot on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361)

Comment: Hey, my alter-ego’s pronouns are vi/vim, buddy! (Nice dig) good answer now that the screenshot app can easily let people choose a different location - I just hope this isn’t a dark side use where someone rolls DIY  malware to spy on others that are left sharking in bliss.